# Display label's value In tabular format In php

Tags: php

In my php code mail functionality is implement. In that mail data display in tabular forma. But in tabular format when mail show in the field name it's display textbox name value. But i want label name value.

```
 <label for="data" class="contact_label"><em>*Name of Data</em>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cnt_input">
                                    <input type="text" name="data" id="bride" class="contact_input wedding-basics-1 required" />
                                </div>
```

Here It's display "data"(This name is given in input type"textbox" name attribute) in table as field name But I want display "Name Of Data"(This is name is shown in label field) In table.

This is My PHP code:-

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {        
      if( !in_array($key,array('action','submit-estimate')) AND !empty($value)){      
        $message1 .= "<tr ";
        if( strstr($key,"checkbox") ){          
          $message1 .= "style='background:#f9f9f9;'";
          $firstCol = "Inquiry Type";
        }
        else {
        $firstCol = ucwords(str_replace("-"," ",str_replace("_", " ", $key)));
        $message1 .= "><td><strong>";  
        $message1 .= $firstCol."</strong></td><td> " . htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES). "</td></tr>";
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please, formulate a specific question and add it (preferably) at the end of your post.

Comment: Solved My question. Thank u so much @simplucis veritatis for give your response